# UDP vs IP- difference?

Tags: tcp, udp, ip

I understand that UDP resides on the transport layer and IP on the internet layer. I also get that they're both connectionless and unreliable. Then what is the point of UDP when we already have IP? The distinction is not very clear. Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> Then what is the point of UDP when we already have IP?

To multiplex services. The **`UDP` port number** can differentiate between multiple services on the same host, using the same L3 identification. Using `IP` only it wouldn't be possible to host multiple services on the same station and easily differentiate between them.

Also, consider the case of UDP over IPv6. Since IPv6 doesn't have error-checking somebody has to perform it: **the `Checksum` field of UDP is not optional**.

Comment: Re "*IPv6 doesn't have error-checking somebody has to perform it*" doesn't Ethernet already do error checking? UDP's checksum algorithm isn't reliable for checking errors.

Comment: @Pacerier Ethernet is not end-to-end but UDP is.

Comment: @cnicutar what do you mean by L3 identification.

Comment: @IanEdington L3 ID == IP address

Comment: @akhan What do you mean by ether not being end-to-end? What exactly does it mean?

Comment: @piepi Every layer is supposed to have its own integrity checking. Ethernet is just one of the data layer format and is only responsible for its own (layer 2) integrity. The packet may originate from an ethernet network but it may transit through a variety of physical media/networks and the final hop may not even be over ethernet at all. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_principle.

Answer (score 16):

Once a packet reaches a host using its IP address, the packet needs to be given to one of the applications on this machine. To determine which application should get the packet, it needs demultiplexing logic, which is based on ports. UDP has port information which is used by IP to deliver the packet to appropriate application.

Comment: Is port information the only difference between UPD and IP?