# Why does UDP exist? Whats wrong with letting the user send raw IP packets?

Tags: networking, udp, ip

Of course we need to specify source port and destination port but besides that, why do we need UDP when we could just send IP packets with the same payload?

I'm not asking why I can't do it. I want to know what the need for the UDP protocol was.

Comment: here is similar a question ["UDP vs IP- difference?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463808/udp-vs-ip-difference). Maybe you find it interesting.

Answer (score 4):

> why do we need UDP when we could just send IP packets with the same
>   payload?

1. IP packets have no end-to-end error detection mechanism. IPv4 has a checksum that covers only its header, so the data is protected only by the layer 2 error detection, which isn't end-to-end. Both UDP and TCP use a checksum to check the data for errors end-to-end.
2. Once the destination machine receives such an IP packet, which application should it pass it to? We need a way of identifying the destination app (socket actually, but never mind) of a specific message. UDP and TCP do that with port numbers. Having no port number is similar to sending a postal package to an apartment building without specifying which apartment it should be given to.

Comment: ha, nice! I didn't take integrity into consideration.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, IPv6 has even done away with any integrity checking, leaving that up to the lower and upper layers, and it makes the UDP CRC, which is optional for IPv4, a requirement for IPv6.

Answer (score 3):

With raw IP packets, there could only be one dedicated listening socket per IP address. IP addresses identify hosts on the network layer, enabling traffic to reach some physical device, a "host".

As soon as you want to have different "destinations" (i.e. applications) on the same host, you need something like the *ports* concept that TCP and UDP have.

For this reason we need a protocol atop of IP; this aligns well with the layered network stack model. UDP is pretty much a minimal protocol to support ports.

Comment: >there could only be one dedicated listening socket per IP address. This seems like an OS restriction. What if I have multiple suckets that can listen on the same IP address in the IP layer. Maybe the router OS need to support it. But is this really just a technicality?

Comment: @piepi you're misunderstanding: what I'm saying is that a socket listening on that level will get *all* that was sent to that IP address; the "dividing" the traffic for different programs happens one or two layers further up.

Comment: Can't a single application running on the NIC distribute the packet to a specific PID?

Comment: that application would be called "the network stack", because "distributing it to a specific PID" requires that the application "hooks" into the network syscalls of the program it wants to distribute the packets to.